# why and how to use Python's super(type1, type2)?

Tags: python, super

super has 2 args,

```
super(type, obj_of_type-or-subclass_of_type)
```

I understand how and why to use super with the 2nd arg being obj_of_type.
But I don't understand the matter for the 2nd arg being subclass.

Anyone can show why and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass an object if you want to invoke an instance method. You pass a class if you want to invoke a class method.

The classic example for using `super()` for class methods is with factory methods, where you want all the superclass factory methods to be called.

```
class Base(object):
    @classmethod
    def make(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Base.make(%s, %s) start" % (args, kwargs))
        print("Base.make end")

class Foo(Base):
    @classmethod
    def make(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Foo.make(%s, %s) start" % (args, kwargs))
        super(Foo, cls).make(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Foo.make end")

class Bar(Base):
    @classmethod
    def make(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Bar.make(%s, %s) start" % (args, kwargs))
        super(Bar, cls).make(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Bar.make end")

class FooBar(Foo,Bar):
    @classmethod
    def make(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("FooBar.make(%s, %s) start" % (args, kwargs))
        super(FooBar, cls).make(*args, **kwargs)
        print("FooBar.make end")

fb = FooBar.make(1, 2, c=3)
```

"[Invoking a superclass's class methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026392/invoking-a-superclasss-class-methods-in-python)" has a real-world example.

Comment: well, this is all? But why should it be the "subclass" not "superclass"?

Comment: @Alcott: for the same reason the second argument is an instance of the most derived class when using `super` to invoke instance methods: the second argument provides the actual thing (instance or class) the methods are being invoked on (including the [MRO](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=mro#class.__mro__) tuple), and the former provides where in the [MRO](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) to start.

Comment: got it, but can't I invoke the superclass's classmethod by "super(FooBar, self).make"?

Comment: @Alcott but in class methods or `__new__`, which is a static method, you don't have the instance, you just have the class, so you can't pass it the instance.

Comment: Results are exactly the same if you just use super().__init__ (at least in python 3.4), so why bother with super(type1, type2) ?