# Python super() arguments: why not super(obj)?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I am trying to understand when and how to use super() in Python correctly (either 2.7.x or 3.x)

on `>>> help(super)` the interpreter tells me how to call it:

```
class super(object)
 |  super(type) -> unbound super object
 |  super(type, obj) -> bound super object; requires isinstance(obj, type)
 |  super(type, type2) -> bound super object; requires issubclass(type2, type)
```

I understand that in Python3.x it's now possible to juse use super() within a class definition, but I don't understand why `super(obj)` is not possible. Or `super(self)` within a class definition.

I know there must be a reason for it, but I can't find it. To me those lines are equivalent to `super(obj.__class__, obj)` or `super(self.__class__, self)` and those would work right?

I would think that just typing `super(obj)` would be a nice shortcut even in Python 3.x.

Comment: I was going to say that it'd cause ambiguity when you call `super` on a metaclass, but then I realized that that ambiguity also exists with the 2-argument form. Now I'm not sure.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The two-argument form is only needed in Python 2.  The reason is that `self.__class__` always refers to the "leaf" class in the inheritance tree -- that is, the most specific class of the object -- but when you call `super` you need to tell it which implementation is currently being invoked, so it can invoke the next one in the inheritance tree.

Suppose you have:

```
class A(object):
   def foo(self):
      pass

class B(A):
   def foo(self):
      super(self.__class__, self).foo()

class C(B):
   def foo(self):
      super(self.__class__, self).foo()

c = C()
```

Note that `c.__class__` is `C`, always.  Now think about what happens if you call `c.foo()`.

When you call `super(self.__class__, self)` in a method of C, it will be like calling `super(C, self)`, which means "call the version of this method inherited by C".  That will call `B.foo`, which is fine.  But when you call `super(self.__class__, self)` from B, it's still like calling `super(C, self)`, because it's the same `self`, so `self.__class__` is still `C`.  The result is that the call in B will again call `B.foo` and an infinite recursion occurs.

Of course, what you really want is to be able to call `super(classThatDefinedTheImplementationThatIsCurrentlyExecuting, self)`, and that is effectively what the Python 3 `super()` does.

In Python 3, you can just do `super().foo()` and it does the right thing.  It's not clear to me what you mean about `super(self)` being a shortcut.  In Python 2, it doesn't work for the reason I described above.  In Python 3, it would be a "longcut" because you can just use plain `super()` instead.

The `super(type)` and `super(type1, type2)` uses might still be needed occasionally in Python 3, but those were always more esoteric usages for unusual situations.

Comment: A coworker once refactored a piece of a method that called `super` into a separate method in another class, so the code ended up saying `super(SomeOtherClass, some_obj).method(...)` That worked perfectly, but it looked just like a bug to anyone who read the code. Although this could have been (and ended up being) expressed better, the two-argument form of `super` can still be useful in some edge cases.

Comment: The first 4 lines of your explanation made me understand everything. Thank you for the example as well. That was the missing piece that I was trying to understand.

Comment: We keep referring to an 'esoteric' or 'edge' case. Is this simply when double inheritance requires we call two separate `__init__()` functions when overriding `__init__()` in the leaf class?

Comment: @ChrisConlan: The cases being referred to there are cases where you are calling super with two types rather than a type and an instance.  This would be for instance, if you want to call a classmethod rather than instance method.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466463/why-and-how-to-use-pythons-supertype1-type2).

Answer (score 12):

Trying a short answer:

`self.__class__` is always the actual ("sub-most") class of your object instance – not necessarily the wanted class, which implements the function!

Replace  `super(self.__class__, self)` with `super(__class__, self)` and you are right within a method definition in Python 3, because Python 3 provides the magic cell variable `__class__` for the implementing class.

And simply `super()` with zero arguments is already the shortcut for `super(__class__, self)`  in Python 3. See [PEP3135](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/).

Python 2 neither knows `__class__` nor the zero-argument shortcut `super()`.

Comment: super() (no-args) is a little surprising. The PEP says its not a keyword, so its a little unclear exactly how it finds __class__ and self.

Comment: @user48956 `super()` is equivalent to `super(__class__, <firstarg>)`. Wherever the call to `super()` is, look at the method (function defined directly within a class body) it is defined in, and substitute `__class__` with that class, and `<firstarg>` with the first argument of that method.

Comment: What tripped me up (making me Google this question) is that if you define a local function that calls `super()` inside a method of class A, but make that local function a method of another class B, then `super()` will resolve `__class__` to be A, not dynamically resolve it at execution time to be B.