# Is super() a function or a keyword?

Tags: python, class, oop, super

The "function"`super()` is useful in python for defining classes such as:

```
    class Parent:
        def __init__(self, trait):
            self.trait = trait

    class Child(Parent):
        def __init__(self, primary_trait, secondary_trait):
            super().__init__(primary_trait)
            self.secondary_trait = secondary_trait
```

the syntax `object.method()` and `object.attribute` is usually used in python but if `super()` really is a function, why does it use the same syntax? I've heard that in java it is a keyword, but I'm pretty sure that in python it is a function (because of the parentheses).

Comment: If it were a keyword, this would be a syntax error: `super = 42`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here: "but if `super()` really is a function, why does it use the same syntax"

Comment: since `super()` is used in a context such as `super().__init__(object)`, why is there a dot between `super()` and `__init__(object)`? (that syntax is usually used when the object name is to the left of the dot).

Comment: because `super()` returns a `super` object, and you are accessing the `__init__` attribute on that super object. Just like `int().__init__`. Of course, `super` objects exist as proxy objects that provide the *next method in the method resolution order*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its actually a class, `type(super)` gives an output of `<class 'type'>`

Comment: but any function is an instance of a class. e.g. `type(print)` gives an output `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`.

Comment: @Natrium sure, but the `type` of `super` is `type`, so `type(super) is type` which means *it is a class*. Just like `type(int) is type`, or `class Foo: pass` then `type(Foo) is Foo`

Comment: @Natrium Most functions are instances of `<class 'function'>`. Only classes are instances of `<class 'type'>`. `print` is an odd case because it is a builtin.

Comment: I get it now. but if `super` is a class, then `super()` is an instance of that class, correct?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, `super` is a type, so when you invoke it with arguments, you just instantiate it. Supporting `super` without arguments requires it to know the current class lexically (using the class of `self` wouldn't work, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43183656/1600898)).

So, while `super` is not technically a keyword, it *does* get special treatment by the compiler. From [PEP 3135](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/):

> While `super` is not a reserved word, the parser recognizes the use of super in a method definition and only passes in the `__class__` cell when this is found. Thus, calling a global alias of super without arguments will not necessarily work.